# Page load hide div and show another

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

how can i control the two div on page load. one div will display at a time.. I need it for login and logout session in asp.net..

this is my code, after loggin, it shows two div.. after logout, only one div is shown

```
Master page.master.cs

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                isset.Visible = notsesstion.Visible =  false;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["name"] as String))
                {
                    lbllogin.Text = "Welcome Back " + Session["name"].ToString();
                    isset.Visible = true;
                    notsesstion.Visible = false;

                }
                else
                    isset.Visible = false;
                    notsesstion.Visible = true;
            }

Masterpage.aspx


 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="HomePageClient.aspx">
                    <img alt="Brand" src="images/logo2.png" height="50" />
                </a>

            </div>
            <div id="notsesstion" runat="server">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="LogIn.aspx" class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">LogIn |</a></li>
                    <li><a href="EmployeeRegistration.aspx" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">Employee |</a></li>
                    <li><a href="UserRegistration.aspx" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">Client</a></li>


                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>

      <div id="isset" runat="server"> 
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><p><asp:Label ID="lbllogin" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p></li>
                    <li><a href="LogOut.aspx" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" >LogOut</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </div>     
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["name"] ){ %>            
   // html code here 
<% } %>
```